# Strange Behaviour of NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration

I found some of the values remained unevaluated using the following code

```
Table[NIntegrate[Sin[i x]/((2^x + 1) (Sin[x])), {x, -Pi/2, Pi/2}], {i,70, 90}]
```

Pick them out, the unevaluated ones remain unevaluated. For example,

```
NIntegrate[Sin[81 x]/((2^x + 1) (Sin[x])), {x, -Pi/2, Pi/2}]
```

returns unevaluated. However, using simple trigonometry expansion formula,

```
NIntegrate[(Sin[80 x] Cos[x] + Cos[80 x] Sin[x])/((2^x + 1) (Sin[x])), {x, -Pi/2, Pi/2}]
```

gives the correct result.

Is it a bug?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the `Method` option with the following settings seems to work:

```
NIntegrate[Sin[81 x]/((2^x + 1) (Sin[x])), {x, -Pi/2, Pi/2},  
           Method -> "LevinRule"]
NIntegrate[Sin[81 x]/((2^x + 1) (Sin[x])), {x, -Pi/2, Pi/2},
           Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]
NIntegrate[Sin[81 x]/((2^x + 1) (Sin[x])), {x, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, 
           Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}]
NIntegrate[Sin[81 x]/((2^x + 1) (Sin[x])), {x, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, 
           Method -> {"SymbolicPreprocessing", "OscillatorySelection" -> False}]
```

all give

```
(* 1.5708 *)
```

So does using an explicit setting for `WorkingPrecision` option:

```
NIntegrate[Sin[81 x]/((2^x + 1) (Sin[x])), {x, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, WorkingPrecision -> 10]
(* 1.570796327 *)
```

To check all the entries in your table:

```
Table[{i, NIntegrate[Sin[i x]/((2^x + 1) (Sin[x])), {x, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, 
      Method -> "LevinRule"]}, {i, 70, 90}] // Grid[#, Dividers -> All] &
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I got the values. I am still a little bit curious about why the default method didn't work for some very specific values.

Comment: @Felix, The error message says _NIntegrate::errprec: Catastrophic loss of precision in the global error estimate due to insufficient WorkingPrecision or divergent integral_. A "local" method is able to deal with the oscilattion around the origin.

Comment: I see. Interestingly, I am not getting any error messages.

Comment: @felix, maybe version/os difference;  i am using version 9.0.1.0 (windows 8 x64)

Comment: but both are the same function. So both have the same oscillation around origin. Screen shot: ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QVC5m.png) that is what strange about this. I get the same `NIntegrate::errprec: Catastrophic loss of precision` in V 10.02 on the bad integral also.

Comment: @kguler I am using 10.0.2 at OS X. Since Nasser got the same error message, I would expect a problem with my copy of Mathematica.

Comment: @Nasser, good point.

Comment: presumably the different form causes NIntegrate to choose a different method

Comment: WorkingPrecision worked. I was thinking about MaxRecursion and AccuracyGoal

Comment: @Felix, thank you for the Accept.